# Get json data error show

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie with AngularJs ,

I want to get json data ,

here is my json data

```
{ 
  programTable:  { 
  program: 
    [  { 
        programId: 1
        programStartDate: 2012-01-08
        programEndDate: 2013-01-03
        projects: [  ]
        members: 
            [  
                { 
                program_member_id: 21
                program_id: 1
                user_id: 1
                program_member_identity: manager
                } ,  
                { 
                  program_member_id: 22
                  program_id: 1
                  user_id: 1
                  program_member_identity: member
                }  
            ]

        }  
    ]
} 


$scope.programTable= {'program': programTableService.query()};
console.log('table', $scope.programTable.program[0].programId)
```

how can I do to get programId value ???? there is error show

"Cannot read property 'programId' of undefined" ???

I am so confused about it

please help

Comment: Async issue. `programTableService.query()` doesn't return the data immediately available to the statement on the next line.

Comment: As @sza mentioned you service may be async, so you need to access data in callback or in case of promise based api, there would be `then` method.